# Chart.Js : How to change the color of a point, based on a third data

Tags: javascript, flask, chart.js

I want to change the color of the points according to a third data.

At the moment, I get my x- and y-axes from a json file:

```
{"data": [{"date": "2022-04-04", "position": 5.0, "indexed": 1}, {"date": "2022-04-05", "position": 5.0, "indexed": 0}, {"date": "2022-04-06", "position": 5.0, "indexed": 0}, {"date": "2022-04-07", "position": 5.0, "indexed": 0}, {"date": "2022-04-07", "position": 5.1, "indexed": 0}, {"date": "2022-04-08", "position": 5.9, "indexed": 0}, {"date": "2022-04-09", "position": 5.0, "indexed": 0}, {"date": "2022-04-10", "position": 5.0, "indexed": 0}, {"date": "2022-04-11", "position": 5.0, "indexed": 0}, {"date": "2022-04-12", "position": 5.0, "indexed": 0}, {"date": "2022-04-13", "position": 5.0, "indexed": 0}, {"date": "2022-04-14", "position": 5.0, "indexed": 0}, {"date": "2022-04-15", "position": 5.0, "indexed": 0}, {"date": "2022-04-16", "position": 5.0, "indexed": 0}, {"date": "2022-04-17", "position": 5.0, "indexed": 0}, {"date": "2022-04-18", "position": 5.0, "indexed": 0}, {"date": "2022-04-19", "position": 5.0, "indexed": 0}, {"date": "2022-04-20", "position": 5.0, "indexed": 0}, {"date": "2022-04-21", "position": 5.0, "indexed": 0}]}
```

date : x

position : y

indexed : if 0 : blue - if 1 : red

To change the color according to this third data, I used the scriptable options : https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/options.html#scriptable-options

Here is what I wrote:

```js
const main_data = {
label: '{{ keyword }}',
data: [],
backgroundColor: "#6AC44D",
borderColor: "#1300FF",
pointBorderColor: [],
borderWidth: 1,
pointBackgroundColor : function(context) {
        const response = fetch('/get_json/{{keyword}}');
        const datapoints = response.json();
        datapoints.then(datapoints => {
        const indexed = datapoints.data.map(function(index){
            return index.indexed;
        })                      
        var index = context.dataIndex;
        var value = context.dataset.data[index];
        console.log(value)
        var label = context.labels;
        if (indexed == 0){return value == 'blue'}else{return value =='red'}
    });
}

}
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Here, the function that allows me to create the graph, without changing the colors of the points.

This part works:

```js
function createChart(){
    async function fetchdata(){
    const url = '/get_json/{{keyword}}';
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const datapoints = await response.json();
    return datapoints;
    };
     
    fetchdata().then(datapoints => {
        const dates = datapoints.data.map(function(index){
            return index.date;
        })
        const positions = datapoints.data.map(function(index){
            return index.position;
        })
        const indexed = datapoints.data.map(function(index){
            return index.indexed;
        })

    myChart.config.data.labels = dates
    myChart.config.data.datasets[0].data = positions
    myChart.update();
    });
}
```

Comment: You are returning a boolean (value == 'red') where its needed to return just a color string like 'red'. So just do that.

Comment: hello, i change this error and that doesn't work. i think there is an other problem. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 errors that are happening when returning the color:

1. when returning the colors you're actually returning booleans, as mentioned in the comments it should just be the strings
2. indexed is an array, so indexed==0 isn't correct, what you actually want to do is check against the target index in indexed

Your final if should look like this:

```
if (indexed[context.dataIndex] == 0){return 'blue'}else{return 'red'}
```

[I've also made a JSFiddle so you can see this in action](https://jsfiddle.net/wu2fek4g/11/)